# nested dictionary get keys sorted by values

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I'm using a dictionary that has nested dictionaries:

```
dicc={ 'a': {'a1': 1 }, 'b':{'b1':2 }, 'c':{'c1':3 } }
# This is an example. I have lots of other keys and values.
```

I need to get the keys ordered by the values. For example, getting
`c,b,a` values: I will work on them in this order; first I need to use `c` to do other operations then `b` then `a`.

I used this to get the max value but I need all the values and use them in order mayor to minor:

```
valores=list(diccionario.values())

claves= list(diccionario.keys())

value_= claves[valores.index(max(valores))]
```

edit: 
i need to get 
c,b,a sorted on this order and without using a b c , because c has the highest c1 value etc..
ok that works to sort a dict in reverse way but lets say i have this data:

1000 10 20 7 2 0

1001 3 30 3 5 0

1002 3 10 5 3 0

1003 7 22 3 1 0

second column is a prior, all this is stored into a dictionary the main keys are 1000,1001,1002,1003, the rest are values, i want to get 1000,1003,1002,1001 (this last have same prior) on this order,

Comment: What language is this in?  Python?

Comment: Not really understanding your question... Are you asking how to get them to print in the order you want? Just define them differently. Rephrase the question please.

Comment: yes in python, i used sorted but just cant get it

Comment: Isaiah, what i need is to know which is the key of the higer value but no only the max , i need 3 keys ordered by some value they have

Comment: Your edit doesn't make this any less confusing. Why not show us an actual structure that you want sorted—not a structure that isn't actually what you want, plus some data that fit into some structure you haven't defined—and what you would like the result to be, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Based on all you've said, I **think** this is what you want:

```
>>> dicc= { 'a': {'a1': 1 }, 'b':{'b1':2 }, 'c':{'c1':3 } }
>>> sorted(dicc, reverse=True)
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

And if that's not what you want, show **exactly** what it is you do want ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, getting the keys sorted by value is easy:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 20, 'c': -3}
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', 1), ('b', 20), ('c', -3)]
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
[('c', -3), ('a', 1), ('b', 20)]
>>> [k for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))] 
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

You can of course reverse the sort by adding `reverse=True` after the `key`.

But you don't just have a number for each value, you have a dictionary, and you want to sort on the `c1` value in each dictionary, right? So, just change the key function. We want the `c1` value of the index-1 value of each key-value tuple, which is a bit complicated to write in terms of `itemgetter`, so let's just use a lambda:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'c1': 1}, 'b': {'c1':2}, 'c': {'c1':3}}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['c1'], reverse=True)
[('c', {'c1': 3}), ('b', {'c1': 2}), ('a', {'c1': 1})]
```

This won't work for your sample data, because not all of your values actually have a `'c1'` key. If you want all the `c1`-less values pushed to the end, you just have to treat them as if they had a `c1` lower than any other value. For example:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'a1': 1}, 'b': {'b1':2}, 'c': {'c1':3}}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].get('c1', float('-inf')), reverse=True)
[('c', {'c1': 3}), ('b', {'b1': 2}), ('a', {'a1': 1})]
```

(The order of `a` and `b` here is the reverse of their original order, because the sort is stable, meaning two equal values get left in their original order, but then you reverse it.)